# Reference for Tensors on graded spaces needed

Tags: multilinear-algebra, coalgebras, differential-graded-algebras

Is there a good introduction to

1.) Tensor (co)algebras on graded vector spaces ?

2.) Tensor (co)algebras on graded modules ?

In the research field of $L_\infty$-algebras there is some stuff, but nothing
I know is a comprehensive introduction, including proofs.

Answer (score 1):

One pedagogical treatment of 1) is Chapter VIII from Marco Manetti's 
*Lectures on deformations of complex manifolds*

http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/math/0507286

Another reference is Quillen's
*Rational homotopy theory*, Appendix B. It is published in 
*The Annals of Math.*, Vol.90, No.2, 1969.

Comment: Thanks, on a short look on the first reference, it is indeed comprehensive. Nevertheless it says nothing about the situation on modules. (Like the tensor (co)-algebra on sections of a vector bundle)

Answer (score 0):

- A very nice book wit tons of examples is  ["*Rational homotopy theory*"](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Rational_Homotopy_Theory.html?id=HLzICw143J4C&redir_esc=y) by Felix, Halperin and Thomas. In particular,  the section on graded differential algebras begins at pag. 40.
- The book "*Seminari di Geometria Algebrica" (1998-1999), Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa* (it is in English and probably available online) contains many details on tensor structures on dg vector spaces. I would start by having a look at the third chapter of the book, which is nothing but [this paper](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/seminari/geo-alg/dispense/GrassiPisa.pdf) by M. Grassi.  Section 2 contains definitions and some results.
- If you understand French, then the first chapter of Hasegawa's [thesis](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/lefevre/TheseFinale/tel-00007761.pdf) contains a systematic analysis of differential graded  and $A_\infty$-structures.